# Browser crashing while loop JavaScript algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Guys i'm trying to write an algorithm where I pass in a large string and let it loop through the string and whatever palindrome it finds, it pushes into array but for some reason my browser is crashing once i put in the while loop and I have no

```
function arrOfPalindromes(str) {
  var palindromeArrays = []
  var plength = palindromeArrays.length

  // grab first character
  // put that in a temp
  // continue and look for match
  // when match found go up one from temp and down one from index of loop
  // if matched continue
  // else escape and carry on
  // if palendrome push into array

  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 1; j < str.length - 1; j++) {
      if (str[i + counter] === str[j - counter]) {
        while (str[i + counter] === str[j - counter]) {
          console.log(str[j], str[i])
            // append the letter to the last index of the array
          palindromeArrays[plength] += str[i]
          counter++
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return palindromeArrays
}

var result2 = arrOfPalindromes('asdfmadamasdfbigccbigsdf')
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: The comment is quite confusing, not sure what you are trying to do... What is the expected output?

Comment: to check for palindrome, you just need 1 loop, but you have 3...

Comment: Lol I don't want to check if that one string is a palindrome, I want to check if there are any palindromes inside that string, if they are push it to the new array... this is a tough one i got it in an interview for engineer manager at google 230k salary but messed it up. was my dream

Comment: `plength` is always `0`, so you're appending all your palindromes to the same element of the array. What's the point of having an array?

Comment: Your inner loop should start at `j = i+1`, not `j = 1`.

Comment: You need to reset `counter` back to `0` before each `while` loop.

Comment: You should step through the program with a debugger to see what it's doing.

Comment: And if you don't know how to use a debugger, good luck getting a $230K programming job.

Comment: First thing's first: I'm not completely sure you know what palindrome means.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mention about the algorithm but the condition

```
while (str[i + counter] === str[j - counter])
```

Make your code crash. A little surprise but str[j+counter] when j+counter > str.length return undefined and the same as j-counter <0. There for, your while loop never end because of undefined === undefined.

Comment: undefined === undefined??? how is my continitionals returning undefined. counter = 0, i is defined, and str = 'string'....

Comment: undefined is not a value  there will be no comparison. for null, sure it works. but undefined is not a comparable entity

Comment: @JohnBryant That's the case of counter =0, as you can see in your code, there is no limit for increasing the counter.

Comment: @user2102266 have you tried with it? I have try with chrome and found that undefined===undefined :(

Comment: undefined === undefined??? . this can only jepordise job aplication if u are specificly will work on  javascript. i dont think an eng. manager skills require memorising "tips and tricks" on javascirpt.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to extract characters from the string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var a; var b;
    if (a===b) {
      console.log(a);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html> 
@user2102266: Test with this code

Answer (score 0):

Returning same sized array to handle nested palis.

ex: abxyxZxyxab => 00030703000 odd numbered nested palis.

ex: asddsa      => 003000 even numbered pali.

ex: asdttqwe    => 00020000 i dont know if this is a pali but here we go

smallest pali is 2 char wide so i start at index:1 and increment till str.len-1

```
for (var i = 1; i < str.length-1; i++) {
    counter=0;
    while(str[i]+1-counter == str[i]+counter || str[i]-counter == str[i]+counter) { // always true when counter is 0
    // while (even numbered palis || odd numbered palis)
    // IF counter is bigger than 0 but we are still here we have found a pali & middle of the pali is i(or i+0.5) &size of the pali is counter*2(or+1)

        if(str[i]+1-counter == str[i]+counter){//even sized pali
            res[i]=counter*2;
        }else{//odd sized pali
            res[i]=counter*2+1;
        }
    counter++;//see if its a bigger pali.
    }
}
```

not super optimized  while + if,else checks same stuff. These can be somehow merged. Maybe even even and odd can be handled without any checks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use three loops. You can do it with two `for` loops where one starts from the beginning and other one is from the end of the `string`.

Here we use `array` `reverse()` method to match palindromes.

Also I added additional `minLength` parameter and duplication removal logic to make it more nice.

```js
function findPalindromes(str, minLength) {
  var palindromes = [];
  var _strLength = str.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < _strLength; i++) {
    for (var j = _strLength - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (str[i] == str[j]) {
        var word = str.substring(i, j + 1);
        
        //Check if the word is a palindrome
        if (word === word.split("").reverse().join("")) {
        
          //Add minimum length validation and remove duplicates
          if(word.length >= minLength && palindromes.indexOf(word) === -1){
            palindromes.push(word);
          }   
          
        }
      }
    }
  }  
   return palindromes;
}

var result = findPalindromes('asdfmadamasdfbigccbigsdf', 2)
console.log(result)
```